# Question about social policy wording

Tags: civilization-5

Aristocracy in the tradition tree says:

> +15% production when builing wonders *and* +1 happiness for every 10 citizens in a city

Is the interpretation that I only get +1 happiness for every 10 citzens *while* building a wonder or is that always the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, Civ V works as you would expect it to, with the wording on details intended to be clear and provide all relevant info, that is to say, without obscuring criteria.

**In this case, you get the production bonus AND the happiness bonus, as they are two discrete effects not tied together**  - if you only got access to the happiness bonus when you were building a wonder, it would most likely be worded in a slightly different way, such as "+15% production when building wonders and +1 happiness for every 10 citizens in a city *while constructing a wonder*"

Comment: Note that this is local happiness and as such, can not exceed the population.

Answer (score 5):

It's not cryptic; that means you get +1 happiness for every 10 citizens in a city AND 15% faster production when building wonders.

Basically the "+1 happiness for every 10 citizens in a city" will be a permanent thing.